# C# ожидать Exception в Unit test

Tags: c#, исключения, юнит-тесты

Есть допустим калькулятор , к нему написал юнит тесты и затем нужно сделать проверку деления на 0.
Как правильно записать этот Exception в переменную expected ?

Message:
System.DivideByZeroException : You can't divide on zero. - такой результат выдает при делении на ноль

```
[Fact]
        public void DivideByZero()
        {
            var expected = DivideByZeroException; // не работает 

            var result = _calculator.ProcessStart("5/0");

            Assert.Equal(expected, result);
        }
```

P.S.

```
[Fact]
        public void DivideByZero()
        {
            var expected = new DivideByZeroException();

            var result = Assert.Throws<DivideByZeroException>(() => _calculator.ProcessStart("5/0"));

            Assert.Equal(expected, result);
        }
```

или же

```
[Fact]
        public void DivideByZero()
        {
            var expected = Assert.Throws<DivideByZeroException>(() => _calculator.ProcessStart("5/0")).ToString();

            var result = _calculator.ProcessStart("5/0").ToString() ;

            Assert.Equal(expected, result);
        }
```

не работает(

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.throwsexception?view=visualstudiosdk-2019&viewFallbackFrom=mstest-net-1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Fact]
    public void DivideByZero()
    {
        Assert.Throws<DivideByZeroException>(() => _calculator.ProcessStart("5/0"));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Assert.Equal(expected.Message, result);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]